# selenium python count the number of p tag

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div class="some_class">
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
</div>
```

How can I count the number of p tag inside the div?
The p tag is empty without any class or id or anything else.

Comment: len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.some_class > p'))

Comment: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

Comment: `find_elements` not `find_element`, see `s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I missed it. Thanks @frianH for highlighting

Try below snippet:

```py
parentDiv = driver.find_element_by_class_name("some_class")
count  = len(parentDiv.find_elements_by_tag_name("p"))
```

Comment: This is java answer, the OP is python.

Comment: yea, I want it in python, I try len() but it said object have no len

Answer (score 0):

If the above `html` is stored in a string you could use `count()` to count the occurrence's of `<p>`.

```
string = '''
<div class="some_class">
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
</div>
'''

string.count('<p>')
#4
```

However, in the case a tag is not closed, it would include the unclosed tag in the count.

To count the total number of complete `<p>` tags, you could use `re.findall()` and `len()`.

```
import re

re.findall(r'<p>.*?</p>', string)
#['<p>...</p>', '<p>...</p>', '<p>...</p>', '<p>...</p>']

len(re.findall(r'<p>.*?</p>', string))
#4
```